# For Kafka sink Connector I send a single message to multiple indices documents in elasticseach?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am recieving a very complex json inside a topic message, so i want to do some computations with it using SMTs and send to different elasticsearch indice documents. is it possible?

I am not able to find a solution for this.

Comment: What do you mean by SMTs?

Comment: single message transformations, https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/overview.html.

Comment: Still, your question needs more details. What transformations do you want to do? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

The Elasticsearch sink connector only writes to one index, per record, based on the topic name. It's explicitly written in the Confluent documentation that topic altering transforms such as RegexRouter will not work as expected.

I'd suggest looking at logstash Kafka input and Elasticsearch output as an alternative, however, I'm still not sure how you'd "split" a record into multiple documents there either.

You may need an intermediate Kafka consumer such as Kafka Streams or ksqlDB to extract your nested JSON and emit multiple records that you expect in Elasticsearch.